# Why my particular useEffect hook didn't run when deps changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I try to control my app in song's play/pause with a state in redux name isPlaying,and when my current song's id change,fetching data and dispatching a action to change the detail information,I want the effect to depend on isPlaying and id,so when I change song and the playing doesn't stop,but why this effect won't run when my id change.The first hook controls the song playing and second controls the song'detail information fetching,the second hook can run but the first can't.

```
  useEffect(() => {
  const audio = document.getElementById('audioSource');
  state.playerControl.isPlaying? audio.play():audio.pause()
},[state.playerControl.isPlaying,store,state.playerViews.currentSongStatus.id])


  useEffect( () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/songsResourceObjArr/${store.getState().playerViews.currentSongStatus.id}`,{
      mode:'cors',
      header:{
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
      }
    })
    .then(
      (res) => res.text()
    )
    .then(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        store.dispatch({type:'changeCurrentSongStatus',
                        payload:JSON.parse(data)[0]})
      }
    )
} , [state.playerViews.currentSongStatus.id, store])


case 'changePlayingStatus':
          return{
             ...state,
             isPlaying:!state.isPlaying
                   }
```

Plus:
It works when I put it this way

```
  useEffect(() => {
  const audio = document.getElementById('audioSource');
  state.playerControl.isPlaying? audio.play():audio.pause()
},[state.playerControl.isPlaying])


  useEffect( () => {
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/songsResourceObjArr/${store.getState().playerViews.currentSongStatus.id}`,{
  mode:'cors',
  header:{
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  }
})
.then(
  (res) => res.text()
)
.then(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    store.dispatch({type:'changeCurrentSongStatus',
                    payload:JSON.parse(data)[0]})
    const audio = document.getElementById('audioSource');
    store.getState().playerControl.isPlaying? audio.play():audio.pause()
  }
)
} , [state.playerViews.currentSongStatus.id])
```

So it confuses me,why It didn't work when I put two deps in deps array?

Comment: may be you can try call stop function before fetch.

Comment: the store object should not be inside useEffect array deps

Answer (score 0):

Your hook dependencies will only be evaluated while rendering the component. So the first thing you have to make sure is that the component is rendering when you expect it to. You can debug this with a simple `console.log` just before your hooks.

Your problem is most likely unrelated to hooks, and related to Redux. Maybe your reducer is setting the `isPlaying` field directly, instead of replacing its slice of the state for a new object?

Comment: I add a console.log('I am rendering') just before my hook and it print,does it means it's rendering?and now I add my reducer to the question,The thing is when I change the isPlaying field the hook work as well as the id field change make the second hook work,but when I add two deps to one hook then it doesn't work,I cant understand why

Answer (score 0):

useEffect(() => {

}, [primitiveTypeDeps])

useEffect function will not detect the changes when deps is an object/array,
try to use primitive values -> following

here are the primitive data types
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

So why you need to put primitive data types  inside useEffect deps array
Primitive types are not keeping references and useEffect easily can check value has changed or not

Comment: Thank for your answer, emm I remove the store in it and the two deps are boolean and number,it still can't work,I edit the question maybe you can check it again